# Exception in thread "main": Unrecognized field

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson

After struggling with errors in my java code and resolving them I finally have proceeded to the running stage, but I get an exception error after I run it.
I am trying to convert json from a weather API to java object using jackson library.
I have several classes for setting and getting the java objects including: City.java, Coord.java, List1.java, Temp.java, Weather.java. I have class named as usertest.java for mapping the objects as a test.

My code is as below:

A sample of my getters and setters: City.java

```
package weather.data;

//import java.util.List;

public class City{
    private Coord coord;
    private String country;
    private Number id;
    private String name;
    private Number population;
    ...
    //getters and setters
}
```

usertest.java

```
package weather.data;

import weather.data.City;
import weather.data.Coord;
import weather.data.list1;
import weather.data.Temp;
import weather.data.Weather;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;

public class usertest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException 
    {

        URL jsonUri = new URL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/4b32c7ef1ceb5dd48bf5/raw/ef1987551faa3fb61473bb0e7aad70a228dc36d6/gistfile1.txt");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


        City city = mapper.readValue(jsonUri, City.class);
        System.out.println(city.getCoord());
    }

}
```

And the error I get after running the code:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cod" (class weather.data.City), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "coord", "country", "id", "name", "population"])

Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no field named `cod` in your city class

Comment: The problem was that I used jsongen to generate my beans that it was produced wrongly. Now I completely changed my beans, but still I face errors. So I think I am doing something wrong in my beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this example is going to help you

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

You need to map a class for the entire response. So you need to have class with the next fields:

```
class Response {
    String cod 
    int message
    City city
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` representation is not matching with `City.java`:

json:

```
{

    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0035,
    "city": {
        "id": 1851632,
        "name": "Shuzenji",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 138.933334,
            "lat": 34.966671
        },
        "country": "JP",
        "population": 0
    },
    "cnt": 10,
    "list": [..]
   }
```

`City` class though is fine but you need to create another class having `cod`, `message`, `city`, `cnt` and `list` attribute where `city` attribute should be of type `City`.

Other (unclean) alternate could be to add these property and set them `@Ignore`..

Comment: Thanks, it has been a great help

Comment: I wrote another class including what @harsh is saying: cod, message, city,cnt and list. But I am getting a new error: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of weather.data.list1 out of START_ARRAY token